# How to use pose heatmap for GAN conditioning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I would like to ask a question about building a pose-conditioned StyleGAN in PyTorch. My intent here is to generate images of human models only in conditioned poses (based on `17x64x64` pose heatmaps). Assuming that generator adjustments are already more or less finished, how can I include pose conditioning into discriminator?
We can use Discriminator class from https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/blob/main/training/networks.py as an example: here, in the `forward()` method of the DiscriminatorEpilogue a simple label-based conditioning is applied.

```
def forward(self, x, img, cmap, force_fp32=False):
        misc.assert_shape(x, [None, self.in_channels, self.resolution, self.resolution]) # [NCHW]
        # Here, cmap is just a simple class label mapping. In my case, cmap would include 
        # a 17-channel pose heatmap from a certain source image.
        _ = force_fp32 # unused
        dtype = torch.float32
        memory_format = torch.contiguous_format

        # FromRGB.
        x = x.to(dtype=dtype, memory_format=memory_format)
        if self.architecture == 'skip':
            misc.assert_shape(img, [None, self.img_channels, self.resolution, self.resolution])
            img = img.to(dtype=dtype, memory_format=memory_format)
            x = x + self.fromrgb(img)

        # Main layers.
        if self.mbstd is not None:
            x = self.mbstd(x)
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.fc(x.flatten(1))
        x = self.out(x)

        # Conditioning.
        if self.cmap_dim > 0:
            misc.assert_shape(cmap, [None, self.cmap_dim])
            x = (x * cmap).sum(dim=1, keepdim=True) * (1 / np.sqrt(self.cmap_dim))
        assert x.dtype == dtype
        return x
```

How could I adjust this code to accomodate my problem, with heatmap dimensions being `[batch_size, 17, 64, 64]`? I thought abbout flattening the heatmap, but that would lose the spatial information. Another option would be to extract heatmap `xmap` from the image and calculate some form of distance between `xmap` and `gmap`(some form of pixel-wise MAE?). However, I struggle to imagine how to combine such a result with the base output `x` for the purpose of conditioning.

Comment: as pose similarity can be calculated nicely (e.g. taking pixel distance or squared pixel distance of predicted and real landmark (or weighted in case of heatmap)), maybe adding this term to the loss function directly is a better way instead of letting the discriminator "decide" about the pose difference? However, I am just guessing and do not know how they did it in papers like VOGUE or the Zalando one

Comment: alternatively, you can add the heatmap channels directly to the discriminator (either add it to the 64*64 layer or upscale it to image size and add it at the beginning). In this case the discriminator will see the difference in pose and think its fake if the pose does not match (in theory, I have no experience with this setup)